# JQL query for MapChange and EntryValueChange by key

Tags: java, jql, javers

It is possible to build JqlQuery which returns Changes for specific EntryValueChange by its key? Something like:

```
QueryBuilder.byInstanceId(1L, GraphNode.class)
                 .withChangedProperty("data").withChangedKey("test").build()'
```

If not, is manual filtering the only option or can I somehow extend the service?

Comment: short answer is no :)

Answer (score 0):

No, all you can do is to query by `byValueObjectId`
using a Map key when a ValueObject is a Map value.

For example:

```
QueryBuilder.byValueObjectId(1, Entity.class, "someMapOfValueObjects/someKey")
    .build()
```